# Replacing strings in a file using an array that stores the find string and an array that stores the replacement string

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a file with some text and need to replace some strings in it. I have an array with the strings that need to be found and replaced and another array containing the replacement strings.

```
fs.readFile("./fileName.L5X", "utf8", function(err, data){
    if(err){return console.log(err)}        


    var result = data.replace(searchStrings[1], replacementStrings[1]); 

    //write the replacement result into file
    fs.writeFile("./fileName.L5X", result, "utf8", function(err){
        if(err){return console.log(err)}
    })
})
```

This code only replaces the first string matching searchStrigns[1]. I have tried to create a RegExp object and use that as the search string but it does not replace the string or throw any errors. searchStrings[1] would hold a string such as "B11[1].0".

Here is the code I've tried using a RegExp object :

```
fs.readFile("./fileName.L5X", "utf8", function(err, data){
        if(err){return console.log(err)}        

        var re = new RegExp(searchStrings[1], "g")
        var result = data.replace(re, replacementStrings[1]); 

        //write the replacement result into file
        fs.writeFile("./fileName.L5X", result, "utf8", function(err){
            if(err){return console.log(err)}
        })
    })
```

I also need to loop through the searchStrings array and find/replace string found inside fileName.L5X but putting the above code in a loop only seems to replace the last element of the searchStrings within the file.

Here is an example of how I've tried to loop the find/replace process:

```
fs.readFile("./fileName.L5X", "utf8", function(err, data){
    if(err){return console.log(err)}       

    for(var n= 1; n <= searchStrings.length - 1; n++){
        var result = data.replace(searchStrings[n], replacementStrings[n]); 
    }   

    //write the replacement result into file
    fs.writeFile("./fileName.L5X", result, "utf8", function(err){
        if(err){return console.log(err)}
    })
})
```

How would I loop through each string inside searchStrings and replace it in the file?

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather build up one regex with a custom replacer:

```
  var re = new RegExp(searchStrings.join("|"), "g")
    var result = data.replace(re, it => replacementStrings[searchStrings.indexOf(it)]);
```

That way, the data is only traversed once.

If you want to use a loop, override `data` instead of `result` that way, the replaced version gets further replaced at the next iteration:

```
 for(var n= 1; n <= searchStrings.length - 1; n++){
    data = data.replace(new RegExp(searchStrings[n], "g"), replacementStrings[n]); 
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first bit of code. I tried it and passed result to writeFile but not changes were made to the file. The last bit of code was able to change the first time each string appears. As you mention, on my code I needed to overwrite data instead of result.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the question but it is not optimized at all. Here is the working code to loop through both arrays and perform find/replace on the file:

```
fs.readFile("./fileName.L5X", "utf8", function(err, data){
    if(err){return console.log(err)}        

    for(var n= 1; n <= searchStrings.length - 1; n++){

        while(data.includes(searchStrings[n])){
            data = data.replace(searchStrings[n], replacementStrings[n]); 
        }        
    }
    //write the replacement result into file
    fs.writeFile("./fileName.L5X", data, "utf8", function(err){
        if(err){return console.log(err)}
    })
})
```

Using the while loop makes the code run to slow. In this case the searchString array holds 7500 strings and the fileName.L5X is also large (arround 6MB).

If there is a better way of doing the operation please post it.